# NUMA vs. Mpi model?

Tags: c++, networking, parallel-processing, mpi, numa

This is from Wikipedia,

> The principal MPI-1 model has no shared memory concept, and MPI-2 has
>   only a limited distributed shared memory concept. Nonetheless, MPI
>   programs are regularly run on shared memory computers. Designing
>   programs around the MPI model (contrary to explicit shared memory
>   models) has advantages over NUMA architectures since MPI encourages
>   memory locality.

Why is MPI model at odds with NUMA architecture?

To me, `NUMA` is an architecture where memory is local to CPUs, and MPI is a protocol for message passing.

What is referred to as `MPI Native model` when dealing with heterogeneous architecture is the end-to-end communication using MPI with all the cores in each processor / co-processor.

Why is NUMA opposed to MPI model here? Any insight? Some closer definition of NUMA and MPI model?

Comment: Hmm, it isn't at odds, I've seen plenty of questions at SO from programmers using a NUMA architecture and seeing their program tank because of the limited processor interconnect bandwidth.  A program that targets MPI will always run well on NUMA too.

Comment: The author probably meant (but failed to properly express in English) that MPI-like programs are at advantage when compared to shared-memory programs (e.g. using the OpenMP paradigm) on NUMA, i.e. _"... has advantages **on** NUMA architectures..."_ It happens often to non-native English speakers, me included :) Anyway, this statement is half-true as explicit message passing on shared-memory machines is still slower than simply sharing the information because of the MPI overhead.

Comment: One of the best way to program NUMA systems is to emulate MPI, i.e. have all threads share memory but also make sure that each thread only works on an isolated section of the shared block, even making local work copies of the shared data if that will reduce the need to synchronise.

Comment: I think it is to do with the fact that MPI takes the same approach to parallelism irrespective of the memory architecture, shared memory models are better suited (light weight) when applicable, even though MPI executes on those machines, it comes with the same overhead irrespective of the model.

Comment: I think you read it wrong. It's "advantages over" as in "advantages when running on" and not "advantages when compared to". Because MPI handles NUMA well, and - as noted already - your question is based on a false dichotomy.